# Docker container can't find file

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

Github repo [here](https://github.com/GuyMichaely/fiction-forge/tree/master).

I have a `runshortcuts.sh` bash script I set up to deploy different parts of my app for dev or prod. I can run it from the project's root directory with `./runshortcuts.sh $args`. I mapped the root of my project directory to `/usr/src/app` and verified with `ls` that the project root directories look the same on my machine and in the container.

For whatever reason I can't execute `runshortcuts.sh` from within the docker container and get "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec ./runshortcuts.sh: no such file or directory: unknown". Its permissions are `-rwxrwxr-x` according to `ls -l`. Wrapping it in a `sh` also fails as `sh` can't find the file. I am clueless as to why this is, any ideas?

I'm using the node 14-alpine base image. My Docker setup is quite minimal:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
VOLUME /usr/src/app
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    tty: true
```

When I `docker-compose up -d` and `docker ps -a` I see:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                NAMES
bdaac49268d0   fiction-forge_app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   fiction-forge_app_1
```

Comment: Can you add your dockerfile CMD or your runing it inside the contianer,

Comment: You don't really seem to be making use of any Docker features with this setup.  Can you install Node directly on your host, and run the script directly, without involving Docker at all?

Comment: I'm using docker so I don't have to install the project's dependencies on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your script you are using a #!/bin/bash and that bash is not available in the default packages of alpine.
Using #!/bin/sh should fix the problem.